# How to see which email address opened my mail?

Tags: email, google-analytics, gmail, tracking, campaign-monitor

I am trying to use google analytics to find which email address opened my email. But it looks, google analytics don't have that option.

Do we have any other alternatives?

Comment: It's a good thing that this is not possible. It would otherwise be a severe security problem in the mail client, as email addresses are considered private personal data.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can't do that in Google Analytics - it's against their terms of service to collect that sort of personal data. The email client that you use - e.g mailchimp, dotmailer etc may have it.

Comment: How they do it then

Comment: how mailchimp, dotmailer  do it?